# MSVC C++11: non-standard constructor inheritance

Tags: c++11, visual-c++

In my Windows Native C++ library I've sometimes overdone it in terms of constructors without providing actual methods with same functionality (5-10 extra constructors). This makes basic extending a C++ class really hard as there's no proper constructor inheritance *(without redeclaring them and forwarding calls)*.

I use MSVC. Is there a way to inherit constructors except the default constructor/copy-constructor using `using`? If someone decided to extend a class where I abuse constructors *(without adding new properties and with single inheritance)*, it's a nightmare.

Example code:

```
class parent {
public:
    parent(){
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << ':' << __LINE__ << std::endl;
    }
    // a non-standard constructor
    parent(const std::nullptr_t&):parent(){
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << ':' << __LINE__ << std::endl;
    }
};

// adds nothing to parent but helper methods
// and maybe self-reliant properties with their own constructors
// so no constructor is required to initialize child class properties
class child: public parent {
public:
     // using parent::parent; // of no real use
    child(){
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << ':' << __LINE__ << std::endl;
    }
    // need to forward call
    child(const std::nullptr_t&):parent(nullptr){
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << ':' << __LINE__ << std::endl;
    }
};
```

This multiple-constructor inheritance nightmare occurs especially when I build a my base CRTP class and need to extend it to build my default class and then allow others to extend and build their own variants while maintaining chainable method functionality *(parent to child)* in order.

In MSVC, `using parent::parent` does not inherit the `parent(const std::nullptr_t&)`. Is it supposed to, according to the C++11 standard?

Comment: "Moving templated functions into inline files is definitely an official hell." Have you tried refactoring tools? Why do you need to separate the definitions from the declarations anyway? Readability? (Note: Java..)

Comment: @DyP Yes. Because all C++ coding guidelines say this. It's easier to read, manage and it makes life easier when you need to use other classes that have yet to be declared. It takes more work, but in the purpose of having others use it, it's worth it... No refactoring. Will rewrite most of it anyways and comment and document. So no automated processes.

Comment: "it makes life easier when you need to use other classes that have yet to be declared" I'm not talking about forward declarations. The definition of members of class templates (like the "implementations" of member functions of class templates) are instantiated on-demand (for implicit instantiation). Therefore I don't see where it helps here.

Comment: @CodeAngry: No, they don't all say this. It's unnecessary to move them like that in most cases.

Comment: @DeadMG It kind of makes things easier to manage... With a separate `.inl` it's more of a set and forget thing. While header only code, there's a bit of clutter in there. You guys gave me a good idea. Will break this question into 3 of them... One is already answered here. I'll have one especially related to inlining library code and one with shortening template inlining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the VS2013 Roadmap from [Herb Sutter's talk at //build](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/2-306), inheriting constructors are not coming to VC++ in the near future:

[image: VS2013 feature roadmap]

They are "planned."

Comment: **(facepalm)** I see great amounts of `constructor` inheritance work *planned* for my future! :) Need to rethink my strategy and create constructor methods. That can either be `static` and produce movable object instances or be actual `methods` of the objects... At least they're brining `auto lambda arguments`. That makes life easier...

Comment: This was included in the Nov 2013 CTP as detailed [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-the-visual-c-compiler-november-2013-ctp.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Delegating / inheriting ctors:

```
parent(const std::nullptr_t&):parent() { /* ... */
```

This is a delegating ctor [class.base.init]/6, whereas

```
using parent::parent;
```

inherits ctors from parent (all but copy/move ctors), according to the C++11 Standard [class.inhctor]

> Question is: Is there a way to inherit constructors except the default copy-constructor using using?

Yes, for C++11. MSVC doesn't support that yet, and according to [this MS site](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/06/27/what-s-new-for-visual-c-developers-in-vs2013-preview.aspx), VS2013 will support delegating ctors (but doesn't mention inheriting ctors).

> I also wonder why, for C++11, they did not figure out that when I'm extending a single class and not adding new properties, it should inherit the parent's default behavior

No assumptions. Your derived class might need to be initialized differently. Inheriting ctors solve the problem with one line.

---

> Is anything like version 3 even remotely possible?

I'm aware of that question, but I'm not that up-to-date with the latest drafts and proposals to be able to answer that for C++1y. For C++11, AFAIK, it's not possible - you can use macros to make it shorter (but not necessarily nicer):

```
#define EMPTY
#define DEF_MYCLASS_MEM(RET) template <typename tnChar> RET MyClass<tnChar>::
#define MYCLASS_TYPE typename MyClass<tnChar>

DEF_MYCLASS_MEM(EMPTY) MyClass() {}

DEF_MYCLASS_MEM(MYCLASS_TYPE::tString) Method1(const tString& aParam) const {
    return aParam;
}
```

Comment: PS: VS2012 already supports chained constructors from CTP2012.