# __cplusplus is equal to 199711 in MSVC, does it support C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I want to know if my compiler supports C++11 or no, and when use the const `__cplusplus` to know the C++ version, I found that prints `199711`.

**Is this version number means that compiler supports C++11?**
Note: I'm using `Visual Studio 2013 v12.0.40629 Update5`.

Comment: Not a dupe of the linked question. Possibly a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/14131454/1639256.

Comment: You will experience significantly more success if you check for the existence of specific language features, rather than insist upon adherence to the *entire* spec. MSVC still hasn't implemented the entirety of C++11, so they can't (shouldn't) bump the version of `__cplusplus`.

Comment: /agree Oktalist & @CodyGray - that's exactly why I've linked https://github.com/sloede/cxx11tests & https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/hh567368.aspx ; IMO C++11 is *still* so broad and new-ish that many C/C++ platforms (uC/embedded included) aren't likely to support it fully *ever*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's an issue with MSVC (i.e. with its lacking C++11/C++14 support):

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/763051/a-value-of-predefined-macro-cplusplus-is-still-199711l

so no, this value doesn't mean anything specific as far as MSVC is concerned. Some C++11 features will work flawlessly, some will fail. Because of that, this C++99-ish value has some sense in it; your best bet is to check for specific features (see `cxx11tests` link below) instead.

Further info:

[C++11 on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212873/c11-on-windows)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/hh567368.aspx

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27459246/719662

[How to Detect if I'm Compiling Code With Visual Studio 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70013/how-to-detect-if-im-compiling-code-with-visual-studio-2008)

https://github.com/sloede/cxx11tests